# Jacobian matrix of function computed by hidden layers of Deep Neural Network

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

Consider the following class that defines a Deep Neural Network.

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 64)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2, output_size)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        return x

    # Function to get hidden layer outputs
    def hidden_mapping(self, point):
        point = self.fc1(point)
        point = self.relu(point)
        point = self.fc2(point)
        return x.detach()

    def differentiable_hidden_mapping(self, point):
        """
        @point: a tensor like torch.tensor([x, y], requires_grad=True)
        """
        point = self.fc1(point)
        point = self.relu(point)
        point = self.fc2(point)
        return point[0], point[1]
```

Let `model` be an instance of the network as follows:

```
model = NeuralNetwork(
    input_size=2,   # Two features to classify
    output_size=1   # Binary classification, so one output neuron
    )
```

and assume it has been trained. I look at model.differentiable_hidden_mapping as a function from R^2 to R^2 and as such I would like to compute its Jacobian w.r.t the inputs of the net, not with respect to the weights.

With the following commands

```
from torch.autograd.functional import jacobian

point = torch.tensor([1., 1.], requires_grad=True)
model.eval()
print(model.differentiable_hidden_mapping(point))
print(jacobian(model.differentiable_hidden_mapping, point))
```

I obtain

```
(tensor(-28.6816, grad_fn=<SelectBackward0>), tensor(-0.4647, grad_fn=<SelectBackward0>))
(tensor([0., 0.]), tensor([0., 0.]))
```

I did not expect to get all zeros in the Jacobian and I don't understand why they are always there no matter what the value of `point` is.

Comment: I know nothing about nn, but the `return x...` in `hidden_mapping` looks wrong.

Comment: You are right, it actually works just with "return point"